# Move MockBean's in a separate configuration object

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jax-rs

We're migrating Apache CXF resources to Spring MVC. It happened that it is better for us to migrate resources to services and have one big controller for all of them. Here what we had before:

```
@Component
public class MainResource {
    ...
    @Path("/first")
    public FirstResource getFirstResource() {
    ...
    @Path("/second")
    public SecondResource getSecondResource() {

@Component
public class FirstResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public FirstEntity getFirstEntity() {

@Component
public class SecondResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public SecondEntity getSecondEntity() {
```

And here what we have now:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Resource
    FirstService firstService;
    @Resource
    SecondService secondService;
    ...
    @GetMapping(/first)
    public FirstEntity getFirst() {
    ...
    @GetMapping(/second)
    public SecondEntity getSecond() {
```

But when it came to testing a controller the following issue arisen: we want to split tests per service so in every test we have to use `@MockBean` for every service (it fails to start application context otherwise). So here is the issue:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)
public class FirstWebMvcTest {
    @MockBean
    FirstService firstService;
    @MockBean
    SecondService secondService;

    // testing /first call only. secondService is not used

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)
public class SecondWebMvcTest {
    @MockBean
    FirstService firstService;
    @MockBean
    SecondService secondService;

    // testing /second call only. firstService is not used
```

We don't want to duplicate `@MockBean`. As a temporary solution I've moved all of them a to base class. But I don't like extending base test class to get this `@MockBean` definitions, it seems to me like a dirty solution. Ideally, I would like to move it to some configuration or something else.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a `@Configuration` class in your test src.

```
@Configuration
@MockBean(FirstService.class)
public class foo{

}
```

etc.

and import it where required, or if component scanning add a `@Profile` to it so it will active when a certain profile is active for testing and using the mock beans.